# Микросервисы и мониторинг данных

Tags: rest, архитектура, ddd, микросервисы

**Задача:** регистрировать некие объекты и с определенной периодичностью запрашивать от них информацию для последующего вывода пользователю по запросу.

Первоначальная задумка заключалась в разделении предметной области на 2 контекста:

1. Контекст текущей информации об объектах;
2. Контекст опроса

Микросервис опросов запрашивал бы данные и публиковал события с результатами опроса. В свою очередь микросервис текущей информации об объектах подхватывал события и обновлял бы свою локальную базу.

Но при данном подходе меня смущает следующий момент: **дублирование данных между контекстами**. В контексте опроса целевой объект может содержать несколько другой набор атрибутов: интервал между опросами, приоритет и т. д. Однако ключевой набор данных (то, что возвращают опрашиваемые объекты) все равно пересекается с контекстом информации (отображающий эти же данные).

Просмотрел раздел замечательной книги на msdn, где микросервис рассматривается как логическая структура, которая иногда может состоять из нескольких сервисов (физической реализации) с общим доступом к базе данных:
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/architecture/microservices/architect-microservice-container-applications/logical-versus-physical-architecture

Исходя из этой статьи напрашивается второй подход:

Объединить контексты в единый микросервис, состоящий из:

1. Сервиса для вывода информации об объектах
2. Сервиса опросов - для обновления информации об объектах

**Вопрос:** исходя из описанного, какой подход предпочтительнее с точки зрения микросервисной архитектуры?

**UPD** В перспективе нужно будет выводить статистическую информацию (Сервис статистики), накопленную от запрашиваемых объектов за определенное время. Но такие обширные данные совершенно не нужны для сервиса текущей информации.

Comment: Хороший и полезный вопрос. С удовольствием почитал статейку, благодарю за неё. На сколько понимаю сервис опроса у Вас независим? Интересно будет узнать мнение экспертов. Как по мне, особо критичного нет ничего в разделении области, главное обрабатываться все исключения и ошибки. Но тоже будет интересно узнать мнение знающих людей.

Comment: Пожалуйста) Вся книга по ссылке крайне полезная)
Насчет независимости сервиса опроса - да, он независим. Вот только вопрос, как его воспринимать: как сервис в составе микросервиса или как отдельный микросервис. В первом случае - нет необходимости в формировании второй базы данных. Во втором случае необходима вторая база (или хранилище событий интеграции, содержащих данные опроса объектов) Для меня в данном случае слишком зыбок статус независимости данных сервисов. По сути, сервис текущей информации должен просто ее вывести. От куда он ее получает - не так важно. Задача второго сервиса - опрос

Comment: Я бы еще поднял вопрос о единице масштабирования/деплоя.
Если они жестко связаны и нужно вместе деплоить - значит нужно слить или версионироваться.
Если один микросервис нужно мастабировать, а другой нет или в разных пропорциях, то сливать их вместе нет смысла (придется делать distributed lock и прочие штуки)

Comment: Коллектор информации можно сделать как отдельный демон, который можно будет деплоить на целевые сервера, собирать информацию и отправлять в центральный сервис. 
Сервис мониторинга уже будет хранить и обрабатывать данные об объектах, отдавать их пользователю в нужном виде. Хранилище данных будет единым. Посмотрите также push/pull модели систем мониторинга (Prometheus, Graphite и т.п.). Может быть вам проще будет использовать готовое решение с кастомными плагинами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения Вашей задачи предпочтительно использовать событийную архитектуру. В частности, задача весьма хорошо ложится на использование брокера сообщений, вроде RabbitMQ, для обмена событиями.

Архитектура состоит из следующих компонентов:

- Сервис-источник информации
- Брокер (шина данных)
- Сервис статистической информации (агрегированные данные, данные за прошлые периоды и т.п.)

Процесс обмена информацией выстраивается следующим образом:

1. Сервис-источник информации публикует в шину событие вроде DataXyzReceived, содержащее свои сырые данные.
2. Сервис-потребитель получает событие, делает необходимые преобразования с данными и складывает в свою базу в готовом для запроса пользователем виде.

Таким образом вы получите следующие преимущества:

1. Отсутствие промежуточного "сервиса-перекладывальщика" данных, данные публикуют непосредственно их источники. Нет лишнего сервиса.
2. Сервисы-источники публикуют непосредственно те данные, с которыми работают - мы не вносим в них не относящегося к их задачам дополнительного контекста (моделей). Сервис-публикатор ничего не знает о существовании сервиса-потребителя и наоборот. Слабая связность.
3. Версионирование осуществляется через версии контракта данных в публикующихся событиях - мы можем сначала обновить сервис потребитель (который сможет принимать события уже двух версий), а потом раскатывать вторую версию на сервис-источник. Независимое развёртывание.
4. Отсутствие состояния, поэтому экземпляров сервиса-источника и сервиса-потребителя может быть (в теории) сколько угодно. Горизонтальная масштабируемость.
5. Сырые данные хранятся в базе основного микросервиса, а статистические в базе другого. Минимизация дублирования данных.

Получаем и некоторые недостатки:

1. Необходим надёжный и масштабируемый брокер сообщений, сегодня популярны RabbitMQ и Kafka.
2. Объём данных таки возрастает за счёт хранения агрегированного представления, но это компенсируется улучшенным временем отклика от подсистемы хранения (выдавать готовые данные проще, чем калькулировать агрегации на лету).

Comment: Алексей, большое Вам спасибо за развернутый ответ)